# Sorting issue with LINQ query and join using tables from different databases

Tags: linq, sorting, join, linq-to-entities

I'm having trouble writing my LINQ query. 
Here's the scenario:

I have 2 databases: A and B
In database A: I have a tableX which has the following fields: Employee ID, Name, Address, Phone, ..., Active

In database B: I have a tableY which has the following fields: Employee ID, Visible, Order

the number of records in table Y is less than or equal to the number of records in table X.

Basically, I need to extract the employee records from table X who have the attribute 'Visible' (in table Y) set to True and would like to sort them using the 'Order' attribute.

This is what I have so far:

```
ADataContext dbA = new ADataContext();
BDataContext dbB = new BDataContext();

//Get the list of records from tableY where 'Visbile' is set to True
var List  = dbB.tableY 
                     .Where(x => x.Visible == true).OrderBy(x => x.Order)
                     .ToList();

 //Extract the list of employee IDs
 IEnumerable<int> ids = List.Select(x => x.EmployeeID).Distinct();


var employees = dbA.tableX
                    .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.EmployeeID) && x.Active == true)
                    .ToList();
```

I'm able to get the correct list of employees, but cannot figure out how to apply the sorting order (present in tableY) on tableX
Currently, regardless of the order specified in tableY, the records returned from tableX are sorted as they were entered in the table (oldest to most recent).

Any ideas how I can fix my query.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I've re-written it all as a single query:

```
var employees =
  from x in dbA.tableX
  where x.Active
  from y in dbB.tableY
  where x.EmployeeID == y.EmployeeID
  orderby y.Order
  select x;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I tried your suggestion but the ".OrderBy(x => x.Order)" statement does not work because the "Order" column is not defined in tableX :(

Comment: I've updated the above example to use a single join. First, you select across the entries of TableX, filtering out all of the inactive entries. Then you select across the entries of TableY and match them up with their X counterparts. Finally, you order and return the X values.